# WPF add Search Function to List

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've created a List of the type "Apprentice", where things like name, ID and occupation are stored in every "Apprentice"-object. In WPF I show the apprentices with their picture and the name in a ListView. Now I've added a text box where you would search for the name of an apprentice. All I got till now is just this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SortedListByName.Find(x => x.Name == searchBox.Text);
    }
```

This finds my apprentice, when I type in the name completely and correctly, like "John Doe". I want it to filter every apprentice if they don't start with the given letter. For example in the list are "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Michael Myers" and "Freddie Krueger". When I start to type in 'D', then "Michael Myers" and "Freddie Krueger" won't be shown anymore, only John and Jane, as their surname begins with 'D'. Alternatively, the list gets searched by every similarity in names. If I would type in "ers" then it would show me "Michael Myers". But I have no clue how to start that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SortedListByName.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchBox.Text.ToUpper());
}
```

Where ToUpper() allows yous to find items ignoring them case.
This function will give you as output a collection of items, which start from characters you entered in the text box. You can optionally replace StartsWith() method with Contains() or EndsWith() methods